# Just listen to Multiple port

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, port, dump

I am creating an executable which should just listen to multiple ports and print (dump) the data. Is it possible to do it in c++? I am only getting examples for server client model.

Comment: [Yes](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html)

Comment: In "client/server", "the server program" opens a socket on "the service port" and listens (perhaps spawning a new thread for each enw connection request).  In your case, you could open multiple listener sockets on multiple ports.  You could multiplex with "select()" (preferred), or spawn a different thread for each listener.

Comment: Linux doesn't have exes (that is, executable files don't end with a `.exe` extension).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a thread per socket/port and have it do the obvious thing.  You could use select to listen to the set of file descriptors and when one becomes ready do the obvious thing.

boost asio may do the heavy lifting for you.   http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html

Comment: I just came through http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html - will this help me?

Comment: Heh.  In C++, you needn't even do that.  Yay `select`/`epoll`.  One thread can do it all.

Comment: @mohan, yes, the version of boost doesn't matter.  1.47 v 1.38 is just fine.  Probably better.